# bitwise AND with if statement

Tags: c++

Can I use bitwise & in C++ code like below. The method returns a boolean based on results of the bitwise operation.

```
bool SetValue( myType a )
{
    if( a & notMyType == notMyType )
    {
        return false;
    }

    if( a & newMyType == newMyType )
    {
        SendNew(a);
        return true;
    }

    if( a & oldMyType == oldMyType )
    {
        SendOld(a);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: For the sake of readability you should use `if((a & b) == b)` instead of `if(a & b == b)`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: those two constructs don't mean the same thing. The second is parsed as `(a & (b == b))`.

Comment: Btw, what type is "myType"? Is it an integer typedef?

Comment: If the values involved are integers, the typical idiom is to leave the comparison away: `if (a & notMyType)`

Comment: @larsmans: I wasn't sure about it - but then there is an even stronger reason to add those parentheses.

Comment: Thanks all. I have another question - if I leave the equality operator out, how does the code distinguish between notMyType,newMyType and oldMyType?

Answer (score 5):

`==` has higher precedence than `&` you should use parens:

```
a & notMyType == notMyType
```

is evaluated as

```
a & (notMyType == notMyType)
```

so you should use instead:

```
(a & notMyType) == notMyType
```

Actually you are using the bitwise AND operator (`&`) but you probably wanted to use the logical AND operator (`&&`).

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** No.

Generally, it is considered a bad idea to use bitwise operations on anything that is not a primitive type (I don't see what that accomplishes anyway). Moreover, I've rarely seen cases when bitwise operations proved useful on something that is not a natural number.

Comment: How do you know `myType` is not a `typedef` for a primitive or a type with `operator&` defined on it?

Comment: I pointed out that if myType IS a natural number than it can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it might be OK with some assumptions and fixes.

Assumptions:

- `MyType` is an integral type
- The constants are generally bit values (1, 2, 4, ...) or semantically natural combinations thereof

Your last comparison looks like a typo (you select using one flag, and compare against another flag).  This could still work with some value combinations, but would be ridiculously confusing at best.

You also need to fix operator precedence.

```
a & flag == flag
```

really means

```
a & (flag == flag)
```

which means, assuming this is all integral and not exotically overloaded,

```
a & 1
```

which means

```
(a & 1) == 1
```

which is not what you wanted.  Either add parentheses or write simply

```
a & flag
```

relying that this will cast to `true` if and only if `a` has flag `flag`.  This condition does not look like a Boolean, but C++ provides an implicit conversion to Boolean. Zero value translates to `false`, any other value to `true`.

Comment: Sorry about the typo - edited it. I have another question - if I leave the equality operator out, how does the code distinguish between notMyType,newMyType and oldMyType? Thanks.

Comment: Edited answer to cover that.  I suggest you add declaration of your type to question as well as any other subquestions or clarifications you can provide if you want it reopened.